# How to connect Micro Controller to an AC device?

Tags: microcontroller, ac, atmega

Recently, I'm working on a project but there's an obstacle.
My question is: How can I control an AC device for example Valve with AtMega8. The valve works with 220 AC voltage. what kinda components should i use? please gimme it's circuit if u have. I just wanna command it when it must be close and when it must be open.
tnxs for your attention

Comment: "gimme", "u", "wanna", "tnxs".  We do engineering here, not engage in baby talk.  *Screw this!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low voltage DC microcontroller circuits typically control mains voltage AC devices through opto-isloated relays, either a mechanical relay or a solid state relay like SSRs or Triacs. Look for Relay modules.

Comment: I heard its possible with Power Mosfet Transistor but i don't know its name. All the thing that i know is that it will work with 5 or lower than 5 voltage.

Comment: @M.Hasanpour A Power mosfet for 120V switching typically won't have 5 Volt Gate voltage control. And would not provide isolation. Use a 5V relay module. It will activate on 5V, and switch Mains Voltage 120/240V.